# how to customize registration new user laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i would like to customize the registration of a new user, editing the authentication system provided by laravel 5.

The problem is if i check the AuthController I can't find the methods getRegister, postRegister specified in the routes. Where are they stored?

Is it a bad idea to change them in their current location?

Comment: What do you want to customize? The URLs of reigstration actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reply my own question if anybody needs the same informations. I found the two methods, they are in the Vendor folder, very bad idea to edit them and there's no need at all to do that.

All they do is return the form view (getRegister method), and check the validator and pass all the data from the form to the create() method available in the AuthController.

Of course all the stuff you need to modify are available in your view (the form), and in the AuthController (the validator and the create() method)

Answer (score 0):

The **getRegister** and **postRegister** methods are stored in **RegistersUsers** trait that is imported into **AuthController**.

And **yes**, **it's a very bad idea** to change the logic of those methods in their current location, as the changes will be overwritten the next time you update dependencies.